# Vue JS, Drag n drop, and Get Ids

Tags: vue.js

I manage differents teams, and a single column of competitors.

With vue-dragula, I can drag n' drop competitors to the team I want, this is working fine.

Now, I need to detect which competitors is added to which team and modify the myTeam variable each drag and drop.

I wrote a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xoco70/vzk27smw/9/

I removed the events because they won't work in fiddle, but they are like:

```
Vue.vueDragula.eventBus.$on(
            'drop',
            function (args) {
                ...

            }
        );
        Vue.vueDragula.eventBus.$on(
            'dropModel',
            function (args) {
                ...


            }
        )
```

How should I get teams Id, and competitor Id that I moved, so I can persist asignations ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kanlidy/tsofafzq/4/

In your HTML template `panel-body` part:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container-dragula"
            v-dragula="copyOne" 
            :team-id="team.id"
            bag="third-bag">
        <div v-cloak
                v-for="(competitor, index) in copyOne"
                :team-id="team.id"
                :id="compotitor.id"
                :index="index"
                :key="competitor.id"
        >{{competitor.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your `wrapper-dragula` part: `:competitor="competitor"` to `:id="competitor.id"`

```
<div class="wrapper-dragula">
    <div class="container-dragula" v-dragula="competitorsArea"
            bag="third-bag">
        <div v-cloak
                v-for="(competitor, index) in competitorsArea"
                :id="competitor.id"
                :index="index"
                :key="competitor.id"
        >{{competitor.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your JS:

```
  created: function () {
    Vue.vueDragula.eventBus.$on('drop', function (args) {
         alert('teams ID is:'+args[1].parentNode.getAttribute("team-id"));
       alert('competitors ID is: ' + args[1].getAttribute("id"));
    })
  }
```

Hope helps.

Comment: Tx ! It helped me a lot!